# How to append values to Model Class

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a model Class, where I need to append values from JSON, I'm using Alamofire

I have tried the below method, but the values are not added properly.

Here is the Model Class

```
class ImageMJ {
var assignment__assignment_name:String?
var assignment__file_up:String?

init(assignment__assignment_name: String?, assignment__file_up: String?) {
    self.assignment__assignment_name = assignment__assignment_name
    self.assignment__file_up = assignment__file_up
  }
}
```

And the fun which I used

```
var imageDetailsArrayMJ = [ImageMJ]()

Alamofire.request(urls, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if((response.result.value) != nil) {
             let jsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
//                print(jsonVar)



            if let items = jsonVar["assisgnments"].array  {
                for item in items {

                    if let ids = item["assignment__assignment_name"].string {
                        print("IDS ==   \(ids)")
                        self.imageDetailsArrayMJ.append(ImageMJ(assignment__assignment_name: ids as! String, assignment__file_up: nil))

                    }

                    if let ifd = item["assignment__file_up"].string {
                        self.imageDetailsArrayMJ.append(ImageMJ(assignment__assignment_name: nil, assignment__file_up: ifd as! String))
                    }
                }


            }
```

My JSON is

```
{
"assisgnments": [
    {
        "assignment__file_up": "media/"
        "assignment__assignment_name": "MAX PAYNE",
    },
    {
        "assignment__file_up": "media/assignments/Calendar-master.zip",
        "assignment__assignment_name": "Doctor",
    },
    {
        "assignment__assignment_desc": "EA SPORTS FIFA 20",
        "assignment__file_up": "media/assignments/Screen_Shot_2019-07-08_at_10.38.49_AM.png",
    }
]}
```

I need like this 
    assignment__assignment_name = "MAX PAYNE",
    assignment__file_up = "media/assignments/Calendar-master.zip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a new item for each dictionary value you have to create **one** item in each iteration.

As the properties are optional anyway you don't need the checks (nor the type casts)

```
 if let items = jsonVar["assisgnments"].array  {
    for item in items {

        let ids = item["assignment__assignment_name"].string 
        let ifd = item["assignment__file_up"].string
        self.imageDetailsArrayMJ.append(ImageMJ(assignment__assignment_name: ids, assignment__file_up: ifd))
    }
 }
```

You are encouraged to drop SwiftyJSON in favor of `Codable` and to get rid of those ugly *objective-c-ish* underscores.